# Validate field in multiple languages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the next form:

```
<%= form_for :user, url: "#" do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit "send" %>
<% end %>
```

and I need to validate the name field, but the page is working in multiple languages: chinese, portuguese, spanish and so on.
then I can't restrict the field just to alphanumerical values.

how can I validate just the dangerous special characters?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to break it down to several problems

1) **how can I validate just the dangerous special characters?**

It depends on what you do with the input date. Do you build a SQL query with it, do you
show it on your web page, do you send it to 3rd party web app, do you run some command line tool on the server and pass the data to it as an argument.

All of these things may have different notion of "dangerous special characters" and handling  them.

So, there is no one perfect answer.

Probably, you need to specify how do you use this data.

2) **where can I get more information on all kind os such problems?**

I really hope that you are asking this question, because if you protect your application from SQL injection, but left wide open some other usual security holes, it won't do you too much good.

There is a very good security good for rails app, which is must read for security conscious developer:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

3) **ok. How do I handle multi language page**

The default encoding is UTF-8 for Ruby 2.0 and up (which most likely you are using). This mean that you don't have to do anything special to handle other characters(languages which use them). However, you are right, you will need to add some kind of escaping for special characters (which depends on question #1).